# I toss a fair coin $n$ times. What is the probability that I see at least one head and at least one tail?

Tags: probability

I've tried solving the question but am not getting anywhere - help?

Comment: What is the propability of not seeing at least one head, and one tail? That means all tail, or all head.

Answer (score 3):

The number of events in sample space $=2^n$.  For example: $\{\underbrace{HHH,HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,TTH,TTT}_{2^3~=~8}\}$ for $n=3$.

The number of events in which no head or no tail appears $=2$.

$$P(\text{at least one H or T appears})=1-\frac{2}{2^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

A well-known trick for probability questions is to 'flip the question on its head'. That is, rather than directly trying to answer 'what is $P(A)$', you instead answer 'what is $1-P(A')$'. (A' means 'A does not happen', in case you are unfamiliar with this notation.)

Applying this to the problem at hand, we know that the probability of not flipping a head at all is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$. This is the same as the probability of flipping only tails. Also, the probability of not flipping a tail is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$. Therefore, all in all, we have

\begin{align}
P(\text{Seeing at least one head or tail})&=1-P(\text{Only flipping tails})-P(\text{Only flipping heads}) \\
&=1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n
\end{align}

You may wish to simplify this answer. It is the same as Sameer Baheti's.